# Prevent image dragging but anything else

Tags: javascript, dom

Here on stackoverflow is a question asking how to prevent image dragging. The code is like this:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){ event.preventDefault() }, false);
```

Problem is this prevents everything. When I click on input it does not get focused. So I added a condition "if event.target.tagName !== 'INPUT'". Now I click on the input, it is focused, then I clicked somewhere else - it stays focused, no blur happens.

How can I prevent only image dragging (happens in FireFox even with background images) and keep all other functions working?

EDIT: I can't register the event handler only on images. I don't have any images, I have divs with background images. Moreover clicking images should blur the input focus too.

EDIT2: Bad solution is below (simplified - written in CoffeeScript) but it doesn't make sense to prevent action of blurring and then do it again on my own.

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
for input in inputs
    input.blur()
```

Comment: By only setting the eventhandler on the images instead of on the entire window.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're on the right track - but excluding input still *includes* everything else. Why not only prevent the mousedown event on images only?

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
    if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
}, false);
```

Comment: I'll quote myself: "even with background images". It does not concern only images but also divs. And both images divs can be clicked to blur input.

Comment: This put me on the right path for fixing my problem. Not sure why it was voted down.